# How to get Google maps URL with a 'placeid' with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, google-maps

I have a URL which I can open on browser and view the JSON data. The URL looks something like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJZeH1eyl344kRA3v52Jl3kHo&key=API_KEY_HERE

Now when I try to access this with jQuery AJAX, I fail to get any results, instead I get an error.

My AJAX call looks some like this:

```
   $.ajax({
       url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json,
       data: {
           'placeid': 'ChIJZeH1eyl344kRA3v52Jl3kHo',
           'key': 'API_KEY_HERE'
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(response));
       },
       error: function(error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error));                                                               
       }
   });
```

Comment: You need to pass google maps API Key

Comment: I'm passing it. It's not mentioned in the description.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I changes the dataType to 'jsonp' and now it automatically goes into my error function and this is what it alerts: ```{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}```

Comment: Don't we need  quotes near the url (`url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json'`)?

Comment: @VijayKumar did you resolve the problem yet? very curious to your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var API_KEY = api_key;
var placeid = placeid;
var API_URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=${placeid}&key=${API_KEY}`

$.getJSON(API_URL, {
        tags: placeid,
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    },
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

If I build it up correctly, this should be the way to send the data correctly to the api, using the `placeid` inside the url string together with the `api_key`.

Then you use a `getJSON` instead of `json` because I assume you want to get the `place data`? Assuming to what you're doing in the `ajax` you made.

Maybe explain further what you mean with `how to get google maps url with place id`? Hope it helps  you out :)